# Trying to get the search text to be put in the url

Tags: python, flask

i'm working on a search system where you enter the text you want to search for in the url or the input search box,it works fine when i put the search text in the url manually and the search results appear fine but when i submit a request via the search box the text doesn't appear in the url for example it results in "http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/" or "http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/" instead of the wanted "http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/searchedtext"

here's the HTML of the form:

```
<form action="{{url_for('search' , searched=searched)}}" method="post">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" name="" class="search-txt" placeholder="search..." name="searched"/>
        <button type="submit" class="search-btn"> 
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here's the Flask app route:

```
@app.route("/search/<string:searched>",methods=["POST","GET"])
def search(searched):
    if request.method=="POST":
        search=request.form.get("Searched")
        titles=db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search OR isbn LIKE :search OR author like :search or year LIKE :search"
        ,{"search":search}).fetchall()
        books=[]
        for title in titles:
            title=str(title).strip(" () [] \', \"")
            books.append(title)
        return render_template("searched.html",titles=books)
    if request.method=="GET":
        titles=db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search OR isbn LIKE :search OR author like :search or year LIKE :search"
        ,{"search":searched}).fetchall()
        books=[]
        for title in titles:
            title=str(title).strip(" () [] \', \"")
            books.append(title)
        return render_template("searched.html",titles=books)
```

i tried changing the request method of the form to "GET" instead of "POST" then take the input from the form to equal "searched" like so:

```
@app.route("/search/<string:searched>",methods=["GET"])
def search(searched):
    if request.method=="GET":
        searched=request.form.get("searched")
        titles=db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search OR isbn LIKE :search OR author like :search or year LIKE :search"
        ,{"search":searched}).fetchall()
        books=[]
        for title in titles:
            title=str(title).strip(" () [] \', \"")
            books.append(title)
        return render_template("searched.html",titles=books)
```

but that didn't seem to work either and still returned a blank url like so:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/search/"

sorry if it's something obvious im still new to this

thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code :

1. 'searched' text input in your search form has two 'name' attributes and the first one is empty.
2. Method should be get if you want to see the searched string in the address bar
3. When you submit that html form, you'll get a url like this : `http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?searched=searchedtext` so you can't use `/search/<string:searched>` to get the searched string

So your html code will be like this :

```html
<form action="{{url_for('search' , searched=searched)}}" method="get">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" class="search-txt" placeholder="search..." name="searched"/>
        <button type="submit" class="search-btn"> 
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's the python code :

```py
@app.route("/search",methods=["GET"])
def search():
    if request.method=="GET":
        searched=request.args.get("searched")
        titles=db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE :search OR isbn LIKE :search OR author like :search or year LIKE :search"
        ,{"search":searched}).fetchall()
        books=[]
        for title in titles:
            title=str(title).strip(" () [] \', \"")
            books.append(title)
        return render_template("searched.html",titles=books)
```

Comment: it kinda worked it takes me  to the correct page,shows the searched text in the url like you said but no search result and i tried printing out the value of searched it said it was None hence the no search results

Comment: add `print(books)` before the return line and check if your query can generate any results. also check if you're showing the results in `searched.html`template.

Comment: books returns an empty list and searched diplays a list of books the problem is that there's no list of books to display,before it used to display them correctly if i access it via url

Comment: ayyy it worked thanks so much dude,on a side note , so if i'm getting text from a form with a get method i use request.args.get instead of .form?

Comment: that's right. and if you're getting data from a json request, you can use `request.json.get`